# How to dynamically scale images per height using pure CSS?

Tags: css, height, fluid-images

This one goes out to the CSS pros:

I wonder if it's possible to achieve a image scaling behavior like on [this site](http://cargocollective.com/runyon) using pure CSS?

Be aware that the images only start scaling if the height of the browser window changes, not its width. (Just saying because all info on the web I found is about the alteration of the width.)

The real sticking point seems to be the different threshold values: Landscape-shaped images just start scaling down if they have the same height as the already downscaled portrait-shaped images.

Any feedback on that matter is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of `max-height`, `min-height`, `white-space` and `%` height.  The only negative is that each image has to have a class set to determine if it is vertical or horizontal.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rgp6h/

Example HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="vert"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/200" class="horiz"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="vert"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300" class="horiz"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="vert"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{
    height: 100%;
}

div{
 white-space: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
}

img{
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.horiz{
    max-height: 300px;
}

.vert{
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they are just using JavaScript to do that, but you can just use percentage based sizes, or  media queries if necessary.

```
.coolImg {
    height: 50%;
}
@media all and (max-height: 600px) {
    .coolImg {
        height: 50%;
    }
}
```

If you share some code of how you attempted to do it, we could try and solve you solution more specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I know that the linked site uses JavaScript. I want to know if there's a CSS-only-solution. ;) I'd like to provide some code but - I have NO idea! Concerning your suggestion, I don't see how media queries should help. Sure, relative dimensions seem to be the only key to a solution. The question is: How to use those specifically to achieve the described scaling behavior.